# Sqlite order by rows order

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

I am using this query

```
"select * from SomeTable group by SomeColumn"
```

It is returns list with accenting order, but i need to same order like in database.

For example the order in database is:

```
p

a

s
```

But result is:

```
a

i

p
```

Sample
[image]

The result need to be like distinct by CityEN but with all columns and order like 1.Paris 2.Amsterdam 3.Istanbul

Comment: A table is conceptually an *unordered* set. If you want a particular order to the results of a select, you have to use `ORDER BY` and the appropriate column(s) or expression to sort on.

Comment: You cannot rely any "order" in the database. If you want to define some kind of order that isn't the order of an existing column, you could add a column and ORDER BY that.

Comment: You may want to add an (or use the existing) ID column onto which apply your sorting. As an alternative, you may want to add a specific sorting column

Comment: If you post sample data and expected results, there may be a way to get the solution you want.

Comment: @forpas added sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement, add this line to sort the results:

```
order by min(rowid)
```

Comment: oh thanks, it works now, but can you answer why ORDER BY columnName work with distinct and not work with GROUP BY?

Comment: ORDER BY columnname works in any case on the results of the query. It works with group by too. Can you be more specific?

Comment: if it works in any case so why SELECT * FROM TourInfoDBRU GROUP BY CityEN ORDER BY CityEN - sorted by ASC? and for example SELECT DISTINCT CityEN FROM TourInfoDBRU ORDER BY 'CityEN' -  sorted like expected?

Comment: SELECT * FROM TourInfoDBRU GROUP BY CityEN ORDER BY CityEN - sorted by ASC returns the results sorted by CityEN, doesn't it? In your question: a, i, p are sorted correctly alphabetically. But you did not want that as you said, right?

Comment: When the column's data type is TEXT then `ORDER BY CityEN` sorts alphabetically and not by the order of the rows in the table.

Comment: No, it is correct. The query you posted: `select * from SomeTable group by SomeColumn` does not include an `ORDER BY` clause, so the order of the rows is not predetermoned, it can be anything. You must always include `ORDER BY...` to get specific order of the results.

Answer (score 2):

In Sqlite, each row of a table has a unique rowid, which you can use for sorting.

```
select * from SomeTable group by SomeColumn order by rowid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not enforce any order with `ORDER BY` clause so no assumption about row order should be made. If you want specific order add i.e. `ORDER BY SomeColumn`. See docs about all available order options: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby

Comment: Unfortunately ORDER BY SomeColumn without ASC/DESC have no effect on the order

Comment: You most likely sort by wrong column. What column this data you posted comes from?

Comment: SELECT * FROM TourInfoDBRU GROUP BY CityEn ORDER BY CityEn

Answer (score 1):

By the rules of SQL, you can't count on getting records back in any specific order without specifying an ORDER BY clause in your SQL query.

In *practice* servers sometimes return values in the order in which they're inserted, in the order of the first index created, or in the order of the primary key--but you can't count on this behavior, and in fact I've seen the behavior change between database maintenance windows or after the database version is upgraded. You definitely wouldn't want to count on a DB engine to give you back records in any particular order if you write a SELECT statement without an ORDER BY clause.

The only real way to get your records back in the order you inserted them is to create a timestamp column and then sort on it during the SELECT. If you don't want to worry about populating that column on INSERT, have that column auto-populate itself with a timestamp (depending on your DB engine).